# python numpy biased probability random vector with prefered orientation

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

what is the best way to generate a biased probability random vector. In other words given a direction vector 'D(dx,dy,dz)' a biased random vector generator will still generate random vectors in all direction but with more likely to generate vectors in about the direction of D

```
import numpy as np
# generate 1000 vectors in all directions
vectors = np.random.random((1000,3))-np.random.random((1000,3))
# generate biased vectors probability
# proba argument gives the biasing intensity or probability to be close to D vector
vectors = biased_proba_random_vectors(directon=(dx,dy,dz), proba=0.7,size=(1000,3))
# biased_proba_random_vectors is a representation, any other implementation is welcomed
```

should look like this in the following image
[image]

Comment: The problem seems to be underspecified. How exactly should they be distributed? If the probability density function is given in some form, you should be able to transform it into the distributions for x, y, and z.

Comment: Have a look at `np.random.vonmises`  (a.k.a. a circular normal distribution).  However, if you want the magnitudes to vary as you show, it's easier to create a 2D normal scatter of points and shift it from the origin in the direction and amount that you want to bias the distribution by.

Answer (score 5):

In general, you should look into the various circular distributions (e.g. vonMises, a.k.a. "circular normal distribution").

As a quick example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Note higher "kappas" (second arg) result in a _narrower_ distribution
thetas = np.random.vonmises(np.radians(50), 1.5, 100)

# Convert to x, y, dx, dy...
x, y = np.zeros_like(thetas), np.zeros_like(thetas)
dx, dy = np.cos(thetas), np.sin(thetas)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.quiver(x, y, dx, dy, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
ax.set(xlim=[-1, 1], ylim=[-1, 1], aspect=1)
ax.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

However, if you'd like to have the magnitudes vary as you've illustrated, there's a simpler way.

A quick fix is to create normally distributed points at a fixed distance (less than the std) from the origin.  The standard deviation of the distribution gives you control over the degree of "bias" in the vectors.

As a quick example (I'll do this in 2D for ease of plotting, but it's easy to adapt to 3D):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Input, higher bias results in a _narrower_ distribution
bias, num = 1, 100
direction = np.radians(50)

# Shift the distributions from the center
dx, dy = np.random.normal(0, 0.5, (2, num))
dx += bias * np.cos(direction)
dy += bias * np.sin(direction)

# Plot the results
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x, y = np.zeros_like(dx), np.zeros_like(dy)
ax.quiver(x, y, dx, dy, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
ax.set(xlim=[-1, 2], ylim=[-1, 2], aspect=1)
ax.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

As a final alternative, if you'd like the magnitudes to vary smoothly, you can use the vonMises distribution, and then have the magnitude be a function of `theta`.  As an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bias, num = 1.5, 100
direction = np.radians(50)

# Note higher "kappas" (second arg) result in a _narrower_ distribution
thetas = np.random.vonmises(direction, bias, 100)

# Vary magnitude by theta
mag = np.cos(thetas - direction)

# Convert to x, y, dx, dy...
x, y = np.zeros_like(thetas), np.zeros_like(thetas)
dx, dy = mag * np.cos(thetas), mag * np.sin(thetas)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.quiver(x, y, dx, dy, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
ax.set(xlim=[-0.5, 1], ylim=[-0.5, 1], aspect=1)
ax.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joe for your answer. How would you transform this to a 3D pattern where angle is rather a solid angle